# Select left 4 characters

Tags: mysql

I have a database table name `monthly`. In that table, I have a column name `month`. In that month, I have few database values 201601, 201602, 201501 and 201502.

How do I write a sql query to select only those that starts with 2015?

From what I researched and tried, I am supposed to use a syntax called `LEFT` ?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT month, LEFT(month, 4) FROM monthly;
```

What I know is that I am missing a `where` statement to tell that I want only `2015`.

So how do I write this statement?

Comment: What is the type of the month column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the entire column:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly WHERE month LIKE '2015%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
....
WHERE SUBSTR(month, 1, 4) = '2015';
```

Or

```
....
WHERE month LIKE '2015%';
```